# Excel index and match with multiple conditions with multiple results

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to perform an index and match formula in Excel with a two large datasets which will return multiple unique results.

I have illustrated a simplified version of the data below. The two match conditions are A1 in table 2 = A:A in Table 1 and B2 in table 2 = B:B in table 1. This will result in multiple results and I want a formula I can drag from cells C3 across to D4 in table 2 to show the results of this index and match.

Table 1

| First Name | Second Name | Food allergy code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Johnson | 03 |
| Bob | Johnson | 04 |

Table 2

| First Name | Second Name | Food allergy code 1 | Food allergy code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Johnson | 03 | 04 |

I have used the formula below which returns the first match, but when I drag this from cell C2 to D2 it returns the same value. I'm not sure how to rewrite this formula so that it provides each unique Food allergy code given both match conditions are met.

=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(Table1!C:C,MATCH(1,(Table1!A:A=A2)*(Table1!B:B=B2),0)))

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use formula? Can't you use PowerQuery?

Comment: Ideally it would be a formula. But if a formula isn't possible I could use PowerQuery, though I'm not sure how I would approach that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following, but it is computationally rather inefficient, so if you want to drag this formula over many cells, you should leave a comment to find a computationally more efficient solution.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D:D,(B:B=G4)*(C:C=H4)))
```

which looks like this in an example:

[image: screenshot_1]